# Is the Black Sky unique or are there many Black Skys?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-2015, the-defenders-2017

In season 1 of *Daredevil*,

> Stick kills a child which we understand is a Black Sky and it is implied that there are many.

But then in season 2, and then in *The Defenders*

> It is implied that the Black Sky is a unique being, foretold by some sort of prophecy, and that one of the Hand's main missions was to fulfil that prophecy.

So which one is it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is anyone who has those killing tendencies. Let me just find the relevant sources and answer this.

Comment: @Edmund Dantes A Black Sky is an entity and so the correct plural form appears to be Black Skys. I don't know for sure though.

Answer (score 6):

**Spoilers below for *Daredevil* and possibly *Defenders***

In Season 1 of *Daredevil*, it is revealed that the much feared Black Sky is a little boy. After he is killed by Stick, Nobu says to Fisk,

> It will be difficult to locate another Black Sky. They are extremely rare.

We also see that Elektra is revealed to be the second Black Sky in Season 2 of *Daredevil*.

These two points are pretty much conclusive that Black Sky is not a single entity, but there *are* others who are simply too difficult to find.

Comment: I presumed that any and all persons identified as _a_ "Black Sky" were really just a potential vessel to bring about the prophecy of _the_ "Black Sky", after the proper training, brainwashing, etc, similar to how The Oracle in The Matrix had multiple potential "ones" in her apartment, but there was only one _actual_ "The One". They were just searching for the _actual_ "Black Sky" among all the _potential_ "Black Skys"